# Bypass/accept Javascript prompt from wget

Tags: powershell, wget

I'm trying to automatically download a XLSX file from an HTTPS URL using PowerShell and the `wget` function.

My problem is that the URL has JS embedded, and when I run the `wget` script it downloads an HTML file that says

> Since your browser does not support Javascript, you must press the Continue button once to proceed

I don't know how to bypass this.

Does anyone know how to bypass the JS element?

I've tried `Invoke-WebRequest` as well, but the problem still persists.

```
wget "URL" -OutFile "test"
```

Expected result would be the downloaded XLSX file, but the output is this HTML page.

Does anyone know how to bypass the JS element when using WGET?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <script src="omitted"></script>
        <script src="omitted"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <noscript>
         <p><strong>Note:</strong>Since your browser does not support Javascript, you must press the Continue button once to proceed.</p>
    </noscript>
    <form action="login" method="get">
    <div>

        <input type="hidden" name="RFA" value="OMITTED">

        <input type="hidden" name="fragment" id="fragment">
    </div>
    <noscript>
         <div><input type="submit" value="Continue"></div>
    </noscript>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try clicking the continue button in a browser with Javascript disabled, while [capturing network traffic](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network). The traffic will show a `GET` request that looks like `/login?RFA=OMMITTED&fragment=fragment`. Put that  `GET` request into your WGET command line.

Comment: On it. Thanks man!

Comment: Found it. @RichMoss how do I add that in to my WGET command line?

Comment: `(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://[your-server-name]/login?RFA=OMMITTED&fragment=fragment").Content | out-file test.xlsx` may work, if you replace `[your-server-name]`, `OMMITTED` and `fragment` values.

Comment: `wget` in PowerShell is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`, so they're the same command. The best approach would be to inspect the HTTP conversation between a browser and the website (e.g. with the browser's developer tools or something like Fiddler) and then re-create the relevant requests via `Invoke-WebRequest`.